# How to I change the scheduled startup installer runs?

Tags: boot, drivers

When updating my drivers, I messed up and ran 2 instances which makes one install it, then uninstall it on the next restart. This is incredibly annoying since it is my network drivers and they get uninstalled when I restart. I would have to restart it to temporarily install the driver again.

Basically the driver is installed. On the next restart it tries to install, but sees that there is already one installed so it uninstalls it. Since there is another instance running, both aren't able to install and what happens is that the driver is uninstalled, but not installed again. It is generally supposed to require 2 restarts so I can get it to be installed, but the next restart will uninstall the drivers.

How would I go about to remove one of these startup instances so that I could just install it once and be good.

Comment: Can you explain what you are running two instances of?

Comment: The driver installer has two instances which run on startup, I am asking to find out how to remove this from the startup.

Comment: Try msconfig > startup. Do you see the duplicate?

Comment: No, it isn't listed there. Is there a place that shows the schedule? It's not a startup application, it is just scheduled to run on restart.

Comment: By restart, do you mean startup or only after restart?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: By restart I mean after any startup including Shutting down and Turning on and Restarting. My operating system is Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Hmm I checked everything, I'm not sure what this is. It is one of the things where it asks you to restart and it automatically runs on the next startup. I found the drivers, but no duplicates, just the one that is currently installed. I am fine with what is installed, but I just want to stop the installer from running on startup. Thanks so far for your help